# How to safely retrieve sql data using a stored function

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, dynamic-sql, stored-functions

I'm trying to write a function in MySQL that gets the password for a username given as parameter, while avoiding SQL injection.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_password_for_user (p_username varchar(30))
    returns varchar(32)
BEGIN
    declare passwd varchar(32) default "";

   PREPARE stmt FROM 'select password into @passwd from users where name=?';
   SET @name = p_username;
   EXECUTE stmt USING @name;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

   return passwd;
END $$
```

When I try to create it, it gives the Dynamic SQL error:

> Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or
>   trigger

I've found solutions involving CONCAT on the web, but that would mean being vulnerable to SQL injection and I obviously don't want that.

Is there something I can do about this? Or is there any other proper way to deal with this situation?

Comment: use a framework (that calls the function) that handles injections. don't use dynamic sql to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using dynamic sql?

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_password_for_user (p_username varchar(30))
    returns varchar(32)
BEGIN
    declare passwd varchar(32) default '';

   select passwd := u.password
   from users u
   where u.name = p_username;

   return passwd;
END $$
```

Comment: What if p_username contains an SQL injection statement?

Comment: @conectionist . . . You seem confused.  You cannot inject into non-dynamic SQL.  `p_username` will be treated as a string, regardless of any weird and strange characters in the string.